# Regex to validate a comma delimited string with a single trailing optional * but do not allow the trialing comma

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to create a regex to validate a string like this:

These are all valid

```
A*,BC*,DEF*,HIJ,KLMN
```

These are all invalid

```
A,BC,D*F
ABCD*   
ABC,WXYZ,  //  would be invalid due to the trailing comma..
```

Maximum length is 4 and only a single trailing * is permitted (counts towards the 4 characters).

1 and 2 character strings are not permitted without a trailing `*`

3 character is OK - e.g. HIJ

4 character is OK as KLM* or KLMN

A-Z and the * only - plus the comma separator

No trailing comma.

I have to admit regex is beyond me.

This is as far as I have been able to get.
This examples limits it to a maximum of 10 occurrences.
This is for use in Javascript

```js
^[^,][A-Z*]+(?:,[^,]+){0,9}$
```

Any help on this would be appreciated as I really struggle with regex,

I could code my way around it but that doesn't seem a correct option.

Comment: "Maximum length is 4"
Does that mean each of the fields can only have four letters (plus the *)? Or does it mean there can only be four fields maximum?

Comment: Maximum of 4 including the trailing * 
So KLM* is valid and KLMN is valid 
but KLMN* is invalid

Comment: ok, and minimum and maximum number fields?

Comment: and fields 1 and 2 must have trailing *? So KLMN not valid but KLM\* is valid for the first two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this regex does what you say:

```
/^[A-Z]{1,2}(\*|[A-Z](\*|[A-Z]))(,[A-Z]{1,2}(\*|[A-Z](\*|[A-Z])))*$/
```

In words: Up to the "," it can be:

One or two A-Z, followed by either a *, A-Z and a *, or 2x A-Z.

Then this whole thing repeated as many times as you like (replace the last * with{0,8} if you like), with a comma in front.

Correct?

Comment: Absolute magic! 
I just tried that with A*,AB*,ABC,ABC*,ABCD and it accepted it perfectly and rejects it if any invalid combos are specified.  Can't thank you enough. 
I now need to disect what you have given me so I can understand this more clearly.

Comment: My pleasure! Always like a regex puzzle!

Comment: Can you clarify this comment
"or 2x A-Z " 

I don't see where 2x is specified in the regex.

Comment: From the first (, there is either a *, or A-Z followed by a * or again a A-Z. So effective 2x A-Z. That is just another way of saying it, I guess, but I hope it makes sense!

Comment: Thanks that does help.
I would like to adapt this to force the first character and only the first character to be A-Z plus @#$ leaving the others as-is  When I try to drop in [A-Z@#$] after the ^ it breaks

Comment: No that does work (I just tested). But if you want that to work also after the comma, you have to repeat it after the,:
/^[A-Z@#$]{1,2}(\*|[A-Z](\*|[A-Z]))(,[A-Z@#$]{1,2}(\*|[A-Z](\*|[A-Z])))*$/

Comment: I did this:
^[A-Z@#$][A-Z]{1,2}(\*|[A-Z](\*|[A-Z]))(,[A-Z@#$][A-Z]{1,2}(\*|[A-Z](\*|[A-Z])))*$

but it fails

Comment: Aha. I think I have it:  

^[A-Z@#$](\*|[A-Z0-9@#$](\*|[A-Z0-9@#$]|[A-Z0-9@#$](\*|[A-Z0-9@#$])))(,[A-Z@#$](\*|[A-Z0-9@#$](\*|[A-Z0-9@#$]|[A-Z0-9@#$](\*|[A-Z0-9@#$]))))*$

Comment: I have another regex that looks like it is going to end up really long   

 The first char can be one of A-Z@#$   

Position 2 and 3 can be A-Z@#$0-9   

Position 4 can be A-Z@#$0-9 or a space   

Position 5-10 can only be 0-9 or a single * 
  
An * can appear from position 2 - 10 to denote a wildcard and end of the string Examples: 

@ABC* 

#AB 012* (4th char is a space)    

ABCD12345*   

ABC 123* 

  This looks like it could be a very long regex and my knowledge isn't that good

Comment: The length of the regex is not really a problem, it is handled very efficient. Of course less readable. Perhaps you can use the same switch as there is in php, one that allows white space in the regex that is not part of the expression, only for readability.
If you want to alter all the characters, perhaps you better use the answer of @The-fourth-bird? That answer is more straight forward and perhaps better to maintain if you want to keep changing stuff.

Comment: @djacks, why did you accept an answer that is incorrect (Mureinik)? Perhaps you better accept mine or the one of the-fourth-bird? Otherwise it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^[A-Z]{1,3}\*,[A-Z]{1,3}\*(?:(?:,[A-Z]{1,3}\*)|,(?:[A-Z]{1,4}))*$
```

Comment: If at some point, I want to allow a $ symbol etc to be available in the 4 character name - e.g. $ABC  is that an easy add?

Comment: I misread your question and this answer requires a * in the first two fields. But yes if you want to allow A-Z or $ then modify the class to: [A-Z,\$] should work in @mous correct answer too.

Answer (score 1):

A word can be represented as

```
S = [A-Z]{1,2}\*    |   [A-Z]{3}\*?  |  [A-Z]{4}
```

Then you may chain the words with

```
S(,S)*
```

```js
const w = '([A-Z]{1,2}\\*|[A-Z]{3}\\*?|[A-Z]{4})'
const assertEqual = (x,y) => {
  if (x !== y) { throw new Error('ff') }
}
const testWord = s => {
  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('A'), false)
  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('AB'), false)
  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('A*'), true)
  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('AB*'), true)

  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('ABC'), true)
  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('ABC*'), true)

  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('ABCD'), true)
  assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${w}$`).test('ABCD*'), false) 
}
testWord(w)
const wPlus = `${w}(,${w})*`
testWord(wPlus)


assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('A*'), true)
assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('A,A'), false)
assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('A*,AB*'), true)
assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('A*,BC*,DEF*,HIJ,KLMN'), true)

assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('A,BC,D*F'), false)
assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('ABCD*'), false)
assertEqual(new RegExp(`^${wPlus}$`).test('ABC,WXYZ,'), false)

 
console.log('OK - no throw')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order in which those combinations occur does not matter, you can use an alternation using the pipe `|`.

For the 3 or 4 character variations match either 1-3 chars A-Z followed by `*` or match 3-4 chars A-Z

```
^(?:(?:[A-Z]{1,3}\*|[A-Z]{3,4}),)*(?:[A-Z]{1,3}\*|[A-Z]{3,4})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^`  Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

    - `[A-Z]{1,3}\*` Match 1-3 chars A-Z and `*`
    - `|` Or
    - `[A-Z]{3,4}` Match 3-4 chars A-Z
  - `)` Close group
  - `,` Match literally
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0 times
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]{1,3}\*` Match 1-3 chars A-Z and `*`
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z]{3,4}` Match 3-4 chars A-Z
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I605xm/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?:(?:[A-Z]{1,3}\*|[A-Z]{3,4}),)*(?:[A-Z]{1,3}\*|[A-Z]{3,4})$/;
[
  "A*,BC*,DEF*,HIJ,KLMN",
  "A*,AB*,ABC,ABC*,ABCD",
  "A*,BC*,DEF*,HIJ,KLM*",
  "A*,AB*,ABC,ABC*,ABC*",
  "A,BC,D*F",
  "ABCD*   ",
  "ABC,WXYZ,"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${pattern.test(s)} => ${s}`));
```

Comment: Very nice and great explanation

Comment: I have tried to modify this to make the first character a mandatory $ which could be followed by the * so I tried this change:
^(?:(?:[$]\*|[$][A-Z]{1,2}\*|[A-Z]{2,3}),)*(?:[$]\*|[$][A-Z]{1,2}\*|[A-Z]{2,3})$

but it only now works if  a * is present  I want it to accept $* or $A* or $AB* or $ABC

Comment: @djacks Can you update this link and add the expected matches, and what should not match? https://regex101.com/r/I605xm/1 Then you can paste the new link in the comments again.

Comment: Good idea . I ddin't know that was an option  [link](https://regex101.com/r/GpM0Sc/1)  and separately a more complex separate regex [link](https://regex101.com/r/GfHfTO/1) which permits a space in pos 3 and 0-9 only in pos 5-10. The first I am close but can't get the syntax correct and the second is mesmerising me.

Comment: @djacks I see @ signs in the examples..should all of those match for both links?

Comment: Yes, the second is simply an extension of the first  the first character in each can be @#$A-Z

Comment: I have managed to get this to work but it doesn't look very pretty. Here is the link [link](https://regex101.com/r/ePrXGN/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd break the requirement down like this:

- First, you have a sequence of one or uppercase characters
- Then, you have zero or more series of a comma followed by one or more uppercase characters
- Finally, you have zero or one * literals

Put it all together, and you'll get:

```js
regex = /^[A-Z]+(,[A-Z]+)*(\*)??$/
```

**EDIT:**
Following the comment, if the trailing `*` literal is part of the repeating subpart (i.e., "AB*,DEF" would be a valid input), that literal needs to be moved into the matchers for the subparts:

```js
regex = /^^[A-Z]+\*??(,[A-Z]+\*??)*$/
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood: The * is part of the subpart, where the subparts ar combined with ,. So: subpart(,subpart)*.

Comment: @mous if that's the case, the matchers for the `*` literals need to be moved back - see my edited answer

Comment: He is pretty specific in the number of times A-Z may occur. You just use +. That is incorrect. And also the minimum in combination with the *. So your answer cannot be correct. I would love a smaller answer then mine, but it still has to be correct with the specs!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get this resolved for a more complex regex:

```
^(?:(?:[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{0,2}\*|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}\ |[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{3}|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}\ [\d]{1,5}\*|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}\ [\d]{1,6}|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{3}[\d]{1,5}\*|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{3}[\d]{6}),)*(?:[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{0,2}\*|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}\ |[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{3}|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}\ [\d]{1,5}\*|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{2}\ [\d]{1,6}|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{3}[\d]{1,5}\*|[@#$A-Z][@#$A-Z0-9]{3}[\d]{6})$
```